# React callback from child with function that was passed down from the parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function in a parent component that I am passing to it's child component. When the child component is clicked it is calling the parent function that it was passed. I want to be able to know in the child component when this function is done and then respond.

When I try to use callback functions in this scenario they seem to respond immediately (before the parent function has actually finished). Any way to do this? Should I restructure the flow instead?

Here is example code:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./child.js";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      happy: "no"
    };
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    this.waitUp = this.waitUp.bind(this);
  }
  waitUp(callback) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.doSomething();
      }.bind(this),
      3000
    );
    if (callback) {
      callback();
    }
  }

  doSomething() {
    this.setState({
      happy: "true"
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child parentFunction={this.waitUp} />
        <div>Am I happy ? {this.state.happy}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word: "Something"
    };
    this.callBack = this.callBack.bind(this);
    this.doSomethingElse = this.doSomethingElse.bind(this);
  }

  callBack() {
    this.setState({ word: "Something else !!!" });
  }

  doSomethingElse() {
    const { parentFunction } = this.props;

    parentFunction(this.callBack);
  }

  render() {
    const { parentFunction } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={() => this.doSomethingElse()}>{this.state.word}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the Child's `state.word` to be set to "Something else" immediately as Parent's `state.happy` is set to "yes", which all happens after 3 seconds.

In `Parent.waitUp`, you are running `callback()` after the setTimeout is executed, but setting a timeout happens immediately and the code continues on and the callback is called. What you want to do is move the `callback()` call inside the timeout's callback - this is the code that will actually be executed after the 3 seconds are up.

In other words,

```
waitUp(callback) {
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      this.doSomething();
      if (callback) {
        callback();
      }
    }.bind(this),
    3000
  );
}
```

Comment: `doSomething` sets the state. This way, when `callback` is called, there is a good chance that the states are not yet set when the callback is executed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation! Was able to get it working.

Comment: Don’t do binding directly it causes a new function to be created every 3000 milliseconds. Create a new function, bind it in constructor and call the reference in setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
  waitUp(callback) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.doSomething();
        if (callback) {
          callback();
        }
      }.bind(this),
      3000
    );
  }
```

You ware not calling the callback in the `setTimeout` and you ware calling it right under that call which would not work since you want to know when [**`setTimeout`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) completes in your child and call its callback.

Here is a [Ripl with it working](https://repl.it/@akrion/DimwittedCompleteGenericsoftware)

Comment: `doSomething` sets the state. This way, when ``callback` is called, there is a good chance that the states are not yet set when the `callback` is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the callback to the `doSomething` function in the `Parent` component and call it after state has been set. PS: `setState` accepts second argument, a callback function which is called after states are set

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./child.js";

class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      happy: "no"
    };
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this);
    this.waitUp = this.waitUp.bind(this);
  }
  waitUp(callback) {
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.doSomething(callback);
      }.bind(this),
      3000
    );
  }

  doSomething(callback) {
    this.setState({
      happy: "true"
    }, callback);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child parentFunction={this.waitUp} />
        <div>Am I happy ? {this.state.happy}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));

import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Child extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      word: "Something"
    };
    this.callBack = this.callBack.bind(this);
    this.doSomethingElse = this.doSomethingElse.bind(this);
  }

  callBack() {
    this.setState({ word: "Something else !!!" });
  }

  doSomethingElse() {
    const { parentFunction } = this.props;

    parentFunction(this.callBack);
  }

  render() {
    const { parentFunction } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={() => this.doSomethingElse()}>{this.state.word}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```